# Calling an onClick funtion from another .java class

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-intent

I've been working on an android app and it happens that it has three activities that call the same OnClick functions which as per the below code is supposed to open an **Intent.ACTION.PICK** . I want to call a method from a class instead of typing it every time. I have looked at different codes and tried but they don't work as I want.

My sample *working* code is as follow:

MainActivity.java

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.ContactsContract;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat;

import java.util.Arrays;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    EditText editTextNumber;
    ImageView pickContact;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        editTextNumber = findViewById(R.id.editTextNumber);
        pickContact = findViewById(R.id.pickContact);

        pickContact.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
            intent.setType(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_TYPE);
            startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (data != null) {
            Uri uri = data.getData();
            if (uri != null) {
                try (Cursor c = getContentResolver().query(uri, new String[]{
                                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER,
                                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE},
                        null, null, null)) {
                    if (c != null && c.moveToFirst()) {
                        String number = c.getString(0);
                        int type = c.getInt(1);
                        showSelectedNumber(type, number);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public void showSelectedNumber(int type, String number) {
        Toast.makeText(this, type + ": " + number, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        editTextNumber.setText(number);
    }
}
```

I want to migrate

```
@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (data != null) {
            Uri uri = data.getData();
            if (uri != null) {
                try (Cursor c = getContentResolver().query(uri, new String[]{
                                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER,
                                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE},
                        null, null, null)) {
                    if (c != null && c.moveToFirst()) {
                        String number = c.getString(0);
                        int type = c.getInt(1);
                        showSelectedNumber(type, number);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public void showSelectedNumber(int type, String number) {
        Toast.makeText(this, type + ": " + number, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        editTextNumber.setText(number);
    }
```

together with *maybe*

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
            intent.setType(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_TYPE);
            startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
```

to another class **ContactPickerHandler.java** so that I don't repeat that code in every activty.
[two activities photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZmytZ.png).

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can migrate the whole `onActivityResult` to another class, but you can do migrate the other things.

Let us say you have the class `ContactPickerHandler.java`, so for the Intent Opening mechanism you can create a function as follows

```java
public void openPicker(Context context){
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
            intent.setType(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_TYPE);
            context.startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
}
```

Then you can call it as follows in your `onClick` mechanism

```java
pickContact.setOnClickListener(v -> {
           contactPickerHandler.openPicker(this)
        });
```

Similarly you can do the whole parsing mechanism to a common function. You will need to pass on the Uri and the Context again and return an object of the string and int for the type and number.

Answer (score 0):

For onStartActivityForResult, I don't think you can move it to another class. But for the button launching picker, you can create a new class implementing View.OnClickListener and pass context via constructor.

```
public class CustomOnClick implements View.OnClickListener {

    private Context context;

    public CustomOnClick(Context context){
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
        intent.setType(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_TYPE);
        ((Activity)context).startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
    }
}
```

To use it, create new object of it and set as the button listener. You need to pass context so that you can call startActivityForResult and the program know where to send the result.

```
pickContact.setOnClickListener(new CustomOnClick(this));
```

For the onActivityResult, because you can't move it, maybe you can create a new static function to process the result, passing the data and context, and call it in your onActivityResult. You need context so that you can call getContentResolver().

```
public static String processData(Uri uri, Context context){
    ...
    Cursor c = context.getContentResolver()....
    ...
}
```